# How to check the differentiability of $f(x) = x|x|$ at $x_0 = 0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I check the differentiability of a $f(x) = x|x|$ at $x_0=0$?

I used the definition of a derivative and came up with
\begin{align}
f^\prime &= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x)}{x-0}\\
&= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x|x|-0|0|}{x-0}\\
&= \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x|x|}{x}\\
&= \lim_{x\to0}|x|
\end{align}

I know $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$. However, would this be? If one plugs in $0$ to $|x|$, one would get $0$, which is finite. But, if one takes the the limit from $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, the limits wouldn't exist.

Comment: Why would you take the limit to $\;\pm\infty\;$ *at all*? The limit is when $\;x\to0\;$ ...and that's all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you mentioning $\pm\infty$? What you did is correct. Since $\lim_{x\to0}\lvert x\rvert=0$, $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Would $$\lim_{x\to0^+} |x|=\lim_{x\to0^-} |x|?$$ That is why I mentioned coming from either infinity to 0.

Comment: Both of those limits are equal to $0$. In other words, $\lim_{x\to0}\lvert x\rvert=0$.